# Issue with CircleCI and Config.yml not finding requirements.txt and dev_requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, continuous-integration, circleci

I am trying to setup circleci for a small project and I have the following configuration yml file:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@0.2.1

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7.9
    executor: python/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - python/load-cache
      - run:
          command: pip install -r src/requirements.txt
          name: Install Deps
      - python/save-cache
      - run:
          command: ./manage.py test
          name: Test

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build-and-test
```

In my github project, my `requirements.txt` and `dev_requirements.txt` files are located in a sub-directory called `src`.

On the dashboard, I am getting the following errors:

```
error computing cache key: template: cacheKey:1:7: executing "cacheKey" at <checksum "requirements.txt">: error calling checksum: open /home/circleci/project/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Same issue - any resolution?

Comment: This can be fixed by copying `requirements.txt` to the root folder, but that's not ideal, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Python orb is a little out of date, but the answer is the same for both the older and the current orb. To specify the location of the requirements file, which is what is needed for Circle to create the checksum that it uses to determine whether the requirements have been updated or not (whether it needs to d/l new ones or use the cache). These two commands take the place of `python/load-cache` and `python/save-cache`:

```
 - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "YOURPATH/requirements.txt" }}
        # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
        - v1-dependencies-

  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ./venv
      key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "YOURPATH/requirements.txt" }}
```